# How can you call the data passed from a different class?

Tags: java

I have a class called line and make that follows

```
public class Make() {
  public static int num;
  private ArrayList<Line> lines;

  ...
}


public class Line() {
   private int number;
   private Object type;
   private double cost;

  ...
}
```

Lets say I have another class called A and I create a `Make` object and add `Line` to it. How can I call the data from what I have to just passed in another class (lets say class B). I tried creating an instance of `Line` but because of the default constructor, it erases the data passed.

Comment: You don't "call" data, you "call" code (methods). Are you asking how to get an instance of `Line` out of your list of lines?

Comment: Your question is not clear. please elaborate